# How do I do addition, multiplication with matrices, when there is a constant (not in a matrix) as well?

Tags: python, matrix, matrix-multiplication

Im trying to do (among other things) calculations with matrices. This is me being almost done.

```
deltaX = -419.375
deltaY = -99.352
deltaZ = -591.349

deltaXYZ = np.array([deltaX,deltaY,deltaZ]).reshape(3,1)

omegaX = 0.850458
omegaY = 1.817245
omegaZ= -7.862245

omegaXR=radians(omegaX/3600)
omegaYR=radians(omegaY/3600)
omegaZR=radians(omegaZ/3600)

delta = (0.99496/(10**6))

x = 3240036.3696 
y = 990578.5272  
z = 5385763.1648 

swerefkoordinates = np.array([x,y,z]).reshape(3,1)

rZ=np.array([cos(omegaZR),sin(omegaZR),0,-sin(omegaZR),cos(omegaZR),0,0,0,1]).reshape(3,3)

rY=np.array([cos(omegaYR),0,-sin(omegaYR),0,1,0,sin(omegaYR),0,cos(omegaYR)]).reshape(3,3)

rX=np.array([1,0,0,0,cos(omegaXR),sin(omegaXR),0,-sin(omegaXR),cos(omegaXR)]).reshape(3,3)

R=np.dot(rZ,rY,rX)
```

So far so good

This next line of calculations are giving me some trouble though and by that I mean the wrong answer.

```
RR92 = deltaXYZ+(delta+1)*np.dot(R,swerefkoordinates)
```

What I am trying to do is the following formula (the RR92).

> [XYZ] = [deltaX,deltaY,deltaZ]+(1+delta)R[x,y,z]

I had a hard time visualizing the formula (and am not allowed to add pictures yet). Anyway whatever is in [] is a matrix formatted: 3 rows one column.

Comment: What is your correct answer?

Comment: That would be:
[3240036.3696
990578.5272 
5385763.1648]
(in a matrix of course)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve the problem:

```
from math import *
from numpy import *
import numpy as np

deltaX = -419.375
deltaY = -99.352
deltaZ = -591.349

deltaXYZ = np.matrix([[deltaX],[deltaY],[deltaZ]])

omegaX = 0.850458
omegaY = 1.817245
omegaZ= -7.862245

omegaXR=radians(omegaX/3600)
omegaYR=radians(omegaY/3600)
omegaZR=radians(omegaZ/3600)

delta = (0.99496/(10**6))

x = 3240036.3696
y = 990578.5272
z = 5385763.1648 

swc = np.matrix([[x],[y],[z]])

#Rotationsmatrix for Z
rZ=np.matrix([[cos(omegaZR),sin(omegaZR),0],[-sin(omegaZR),cos(omegaZR),0],[0,0,1]])

#Rotationsmatrix for Y
rY=np.matrix([[cos(omegaYR),0,-sin(omegaYR)],[0,1,0],[sin(omegaYR),0,cos(omegaYR)]])

#Rotationsmatrix for X
rX=np.matrix([[1,0,0],[0,cos(omegaXR),sin(omegaXR)],[0,-sin(omegaXR),cos(omegaXR)]]).reshape(3,3)

R=rZ*rY*rX

#calculation
RR92 = deltaXYZ + (delta+1) * (R*swc)

print RR92
```

## Correct:

3239535.0069
990625.8659
5385201.6355

Answer (score 0):

For quick result, I convert np.array to matrix and do the computation as follows:

```
import numpy as np
from numpy import radians, cos, sin, matrix

deltaX = -419.375
deltaY = -99.352
deltaZ = -591.349

deltaXYZ = np.array([deltaX,deltaY,deltaZ]).reshape(3,1)
delXYZ = matrix(deltaXYZ)  # matrix

omegaX = 0.850458
omegaY = 1.817245
omegaZ= -7.862245

omegaXR=radians(omegaX/3600)
omegaYR=radians(omegaY/3600)
omegaZR=radians(omegaZ/3600)

delta = (0.99496/(10**6))

x = 3240036.3696 
y = 990578.5272  
z = 5385763.1648 

swerefkoordinates = np.array([x,y,z]).reshape(1,3)  # 3*1
swc = matrix(swerefkoordinates)  # matrix

rZ=np.array([cos(omegaZR),sin(omegaZR),0,-     sin(omegaZR),cos(omegaZR),0,0,0,1]).reshape(3,3)

rY=np.array([cos(omegaYR),0,-sin(omegaYR),0,1,0,sin(omegaYR),0,cos(omegaYR)]).reshape(3,3)

rX=np.array([1,0,0,0,cos(omegaXR),sin(omegaXR),0,-sin(omegaXR),cos(omegaXR)]).reshape(3,3)

R=np.dot(rZ,rY,rX)
mR = matrix(R)  # matrix

# finally,
RR92 = delXYZ + (delta+1) * (mR*swc.T)  # matrix operatoionz
RR92

# Output
# matrix([[ 3239535.00769073],
#        [  990603.65962255],
#        [ 5385205.71977643]])
```

Comment: Changing the arrays to matrices seems like a good Idea, however the answer is still wrong, it should be: 
X: 3239535.0069
Y: 990625.8659
Z: 5385201.6355
Also I don´t really understand the 'T' in "swc.T".

Comment: Good to know that you have found the solution. Actually, you can solve it without using `np.matrix()`, but using it is recommended for checking the result. By the way, `swc.T` is the transpose of swc.